# How to enable multiple words on Quicklook search?

Tags: macos, catalina, trackpad, quicklook

I'm trying to use Quicklook feature by using the Force touch of the Macbook Pro's 2018 (with Catalina) trackpad with multiple words but I can only use it with single words.

Like in the following picture:

> [image]

If I select more than one word for Quicklook it will only search the one above the mouse. I have seen the feature used in the MacBook pro 2019 and it supports multiple words quicklook.

Like in the following picture:

> [image]

Do Macbooks 2018 and earlier supports this QuickLook force touch feature for multiple words?. If that is the case, how can be configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Macbooks 2018 and earlier supports this quicklook force touch feature for multiple words?

I have MacBook 2017, macOS Mojave. Multiple words are picked up in Safari when they start with Capital letters, for e.g. proper nouns. This however won't work in Firefox.

I am not aware of configuration.

Comment: You are right, it's only supported in safari and not in firefox. Thanks for the answer